# Core Data Reverse Ordered Relationship Fetch

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I would like to be able to fetch all entities of a to-many relationship that is ordered.  However, I need them to be in the reverse order. I'm using a `fetchedResultsController`  and don't know how to accomplish this.  The ordered relationship works, but I want it descending, rather than ascending.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The "ordering" is only a feature of the to-many relationship from one entity to another entity. It does not have any effect on the results of a Core Data fetch request. (Imagine you have two ordered relationships `A <->> C` and `B <-->> C` and you fetch all `C` objects. Which of the two orderings should be used?)

Comment: @MartinR That puts things into perspective.  I won't be using an ordered relationship to achieve what I need, but a timestamp instead.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You must be using a Sort Desrciptor to fetch the values in ascending order.

```
+ (id)sortDescriptorWithKey:(NSString *)key ascending:(BOOL)ascending
```

If you pass `YES` as a BOOL to `ascending` , then it returns a sortDesriptor that sorts ascendingly.
If you pass `NO` as a BOOL to `ascending` , then it returns a sortDesriptor that sorts descendingly.

**EDIT:**
If I am not wrong then Core Data returns `NSOrderedSet` for ordered to-many relationships.
You can use this method on returned NSOrederedSet object to get a reverse NSOrderedSet

```
NSOrderedSet *reversedResutsSet = [yourOrderedSet reversedOrderedSet];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Technically I'm not sorting by any attribute.  The order comes from the fact that my to-many relationship is "ordered".